# Removing gap between polygons in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, line, merge

I have a large shapefile with polygons. Some of them have roads between them, but apparently the roads have been deleted. Therefore, there is only space between the polygons. I want them removed in ArcMap. I need my solution to be automated since the data is large so snapping and such cannot be used. What I could think of was to add in the roads shapefile but I am not sure where to go from there. I was thinking I can have the polygons meet half-way, at the middle of the space (roads) between them.

Any idea how to do that?

This is how my map looks like now:

[image]

Comment: I think your question would benefit from you including a picture of your input and desired output data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a pic of my map. The desired output would be for the gap to be removed.

Comment: I would just create a polygon around your data in a separate feature class and Union the two feature classes. Then clean up any unwanted fields added by the process.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm kinda new to ArcMap - how would I create a polygon around my data?

Comment: If it's an exact rectangle then you could use Create Fishnet to create a single polygon vector grid.

Comment: It's not. It's a city map...

Comment: Then create an empty feature class of type polygon and decide whether you're happy with a rough polygon quickly digitized is good enough or whether to use the Trace tool for accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for replying to me. This all sounds very complex and I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps search Google for things like "inserting roads polygon into cadastre without roads".

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: or try a buffer with one half the roa width, and then use some overlay operation(difference I think?). it will probably not be beautiful, but may work

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the AutoComplete polygon.

These are a few supporting documents that you can refer to for a better understanding.

[Fill the space between polygon features](https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/fill-the-space-between-polygon-features/td-p/240617)

[Creating adjoining polygons](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-adjoining-polygons.htm)

[Aggregate Polygons](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/aggregate-polygons.htm)